# usage of the word "have" in "I have her"

Tags: word-meaning

> I  can't do with anything unless I **have her** all to myself.

In this sentence, what does **have** mean?
Does it mean *control*?

Comment: The answers on this question are superior than of the older question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What difference would that make?

Comment: @P.E.Dant well we would want new answers to go to the place most users are likely to land. I agree with Mari-Lou but I clicked the button too quick and didn't want to rock the boat. Let me see if I can fix it. I like the question better on the other one though. There's more meat to it. even though there are good answers here. I don't want to merge them because "I have her all to myself" is more general than "to have Helen". Let me ask the other mods what they think.

Comment: @ColleenV My comment sounded cynical, I now realize, when it was meant to say pretty much what you just said (and would have done if I hadn't been dashing out the door.) And if only there were a way to somehow _combine_ questions on a single page. Sometimes two of them together create a useful synthesis.

Answer (score 4):

To **have** someone or something entirely to oneself means that the person or thing in question will be occupied solely with or for one's own concerns.

The operative definition of **have** here is:

> To cause to be in a specified place or state: *had the guests in the dining room; had everyone fascinated*

<sup><sub>[Definition from TFD Online](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/have)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 4):

*The Oxford English Dictionary (OED)* "has" for this usage of the verb *to have:*

> **c.to have (something or someone) to oneself:** to be able to enjoy, use, or occupy (a thing) without having to share it with anyone else; to have (a person's) undivided attention.

The *Random House Learner's Dictionary* and [*Dictionary.com*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/have?s=t) include this discursion on the verb *have,* which concisely describes its broad utility:

> 1. **Have, hold, occupy, own, possess** mean to be, in varying degrees, in possession of something. Have, being the most general word, admits of the widest range of application: *to have money, rights, discretion, a disease, a glimpse, an idea; to have a friend's umbrella.*

A student of English who masters the diverse uses and meanings of the verb *to have* will benefit greatly in any subsequent study of the language.

Answer (score 0):

For that specific sentence it means to either have her whole attention or to be the only one with that specific type of relationship with her

> I have a computer all to myself

would mean I am not sharing the computer with anyone else